# I got a error on code data.docs . I want to display all data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[I have an error on data.docs . It always show an error on the docs code. i want to display all the data from firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY3Un.png)

Comment: Add your error log here and also relevant code

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. I'd also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there gives you the best chance that someone can help.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, it seems you have not set a return type for your FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder. If you wish to access properties on snapshot.data, you should type the future or stream. For example doing

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
```

allows you to access methods on the QuerySnapshot class like

```
snapshot.data!.docs
```